# Order polymorphic comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

shared/_comments.html.haml

```
#comments
  - commentable.comments.each do |comment|
    = link_to image_tag(avatar_url comment.user_id,36), :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => comment.user_id
    = comment.content
    %br
```

How to order polymorphic comments by 'created_at DESC'  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model:

```
scope :by_created_at, order('created_at DESC')
```

Then in your view:

```
- commentable.comments.by_created_at.each do |comment|
```